# Delete data using webservice iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I delete data using web service?

I have `UILabel` as `uiOid` in `CustomTableviewCell.h`. Now I am using `uiOid` as `cell.uiOid.text=[orid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in ViewController.m. Here `orid` is `NSMutablearray` for retrieving records from webservice. I retrieved data correctly, but my problem is How can I delete? I am using webservice to delete data.

I inserted delete webservice in

**//Updated//**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {      
    [desc removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [item removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cpack removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [uprice removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cprice removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [quantity removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [total removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [orid removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSLog(@"%@",[uid objectForKey:@"OID"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",orid);


    NSString *soapmessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<DeleteValue xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                             "<oid>%@</oid>"
                             "</DeleteValue>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n",orid

                             ];

    NSLog(@"%@",soapmessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",appdev.hostname]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapmessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/DeleteVaue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapmessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

[mytableview reloadData];

}
```

method. When I put static number "89291", data successfully deleted(Not useful for multiple operation). But I want to pass `orid (NSMutableArray)` in webservice instead of static number. How can I fix this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can send array. but for that webservice is also needed to be changed.

Comment: @HinataHyuga. I am ready to change WS

Comment: so wherever you are passing string in webservice, use array instead. and in webservice fetch that array and delete all those entries.

Comment: u did down vote for my answer.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from yourDataAry

```
[orid removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

And make a webService to delete this record from ServerDataBase too.

Answer (score 0):

pass this in your delete service method:

```
[orid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It is executed every time a row is deleted from table. After that:

```
[orid removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[aTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: No, it cause crash.Thanx 4 help

Comment: how do you want to delete it by swiping?